# Properties of mean and standard deviation of a random variable?

Tags: probability

Along with the knowledge of the shape of a given probability distribution - what practical information does the mean and standard deviation of a random variable provide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mean is measure of location and the standard deviation is a measure of scale.

If a random variable $X$ has mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$ and you use  define a new random variable as $Y=X+a$ then the mean of $Y$ is $\mu+a$.  Similarly if you define $Z = bX$ then the standard deviation of $Z$ is $b\sigma$.  More generally for a linear transformation, if $W=bX+a$ then the mean of $W$ is $b\mu +a$ and the standard deviation of $W$ is $b\sigma$.

There are other statistics with similar properties, such as the median and inter-quartile range.

If the mean and standard deviation exist then the distribution is not "too dispersed", and you can apply the central limit theorem.

Answer (score 1):

- Mean tells you around which point is the distribution concentrated on.
- Standard deviation tells you, hoe dispersed is the distribution around the mean. The greater the dispersion of values, the larger the standard deviation.

Answer (score 1):

To flesh out Kannappan Sampath's answer a little, you can use Chebyshev's inequality to assert that the probability that $X$ deviates from its mean $\mu$
by at least $\alpha$ *standard deviations* is *at most* $1/\alpha^2$, that is,

$$P\{X \leq \mu - \alpha\sigma\} + P\{X \geq  \mu + \alpha\sigma\}
= P\{|X-\mu| \geq \alpha\sigma\} \leq \frac{1}{\alpha^2}$$
where $\sigma$ denotes the standard deviation.

Answer (score 1):

Properties of mean:

1. It is responsive to the exact proportions of each score in a distribution.
2. Since mean is directly proportional to sum of scores and inversely proportional to number of score, changes in values of either will affect the mean.
3. Much like a seesaw that includes a board and a fulcrum, the mean represents the fulcrum which is the balance point and the scores are spread out on the board. Changes in the scores can change the balance.
4. The sum of scores minus the mean= 0
5. Sum of negative deviation from the mean is equal to sum of positive deviation from the mean.
6. Mean has a stability from sample to sample.
7. When a distribution is bell shaped, the mean is most resistant to change sampling variations. This makes the mean a valuable indicator of what is true in a population with regard to central tendency.
   8)When measures of central tendencies should reflect the total scores, the mean is the best choice.

Properties of Standard Deviation:

1. It is related to the mean, responsive to each score in a distribution (useful with open ended distributions).
2. When scores move away from the mean, there is an increase in standard deviation. When scores move closer to the mean, there is a decrease in standard deviation.
3. The standard deviation is affected by scores that lie at the extreme ends of a distribution.
4. When there are a few extreme scores or the data is badly skewed, the standard deviation is not best.
5. Standard deviation is not independent of  change of scale.
6. Increase in dispersion or variation leads to increase in standard deviation and increase in magnitude of deviation of the value from the mean.
7. Standard deviation lies embedded in both descriptive and inferential statistics.